# How to search values in boto3 python2.7 list dict object - list_tags_for_resource

Tags: python-2.7, boto3

I have respone object below

```
response = source.list_tags_for_resource(ResourceName=<ARN>)
    taglistk = response['TagList']
    print(taglistk)
```

output :

```
[{'Value': 'yes', 'Key': 'az'},{'Value': 'dba', 'Key': 'created'},{'Value': 'mariadb', 'Key': 'service'}]
```

Now I want to write an for if condition to match for only K,V az=yes and service=mariadb and do something

Answer (score 0):

From the tag list of the response, pick a tag by for loop and check the values of given keys, i.e. Key and Value.

```
response = source.list_tags_for_resource(ResourceName=<ARN>)

for item in response:
    if item['Key'] == 'az' and item['Value'] == 'yes':
        # do something with item
    elif item['Key'] == 'service' and item['Value'] == 'mariadb':
        # do otherthing with item
    else:
        continue
```

Comment: actually I have to check both the conditions before do anything with the items. First If condition should check the both k,v pairs and do something..

Comment: They are seperated items and how an item satisfy those two conditions at the same time? I dont get.it what you mean.